# Is it possible to include one MetaPost file into another?

Tags: metapost

I have two metapost files:

```
% test1.mp
beginfig(1):

% foobar code

% code specific to test1

endfig;
end;
```

---

```
% test2.mp
beginfig(1):

% foobar code    

% code specific to test2

endfig;
end;
```

As a programmer, I naturally hate duplication. Is there a way of moving the "foobar code" into a foobar.mp file, and then including this file in both test1.mp and test2.mp? For example...

```
% test1.mp
beginfig(1):

% for illustration...
Include.foobar("foobar.mp");

% code specific to test2

endfig;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
% test1.mp
beginfig(1):
input foobar
endfig;
end;
```

Comment: Is the `input` command documented anywhere? I tried to search info about it and cannot find anything.

Comment: Also, the input mechanism seems not to work when using the mplib built into lualatex --- any sort of solution / work-around?